# MYSQL BOOLEAN SEARCH. Different results from mariaDB vs Percona

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

Server A is a live server where I do not have access and is running Percona 5.5.43

Server B is a production server and is running MariaDB 10.1.19

Do not ask me why they have different setups, that is what I am given.

When I run the following query on the same dataset:

```
SELECT fields , MATCH(field1,field2) AGAINST ('SEARCHTERM' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  AS m 
FROM TABLE  
WHERE MATCH(field1,field2)  AGAINST ('SEARCHTERM' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY M 
DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

I get a completely different resultset.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: I guess it is just in a different order (limited to 50).

Comment: Which `ENGINE` is each using?  There are minor differences in results between MyISAM and InnoDB.  Please elaborate on what differences you are getting -- perhaps start with an example of the query and the diff results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `ORDER BY M DESC` to get the *most* relevant first.

After that, the differences between `ENGINE=MyISAM` and `InnoDB` may be less pronounced.

Comment: My mistake , the original query had the DESC attribute to it.  I asked after the live server ( server A) and they are running a MyISAM database engine and they put a INNODB engine on the production. That clears it up.  Thank you!